# Image from concept of a convolutional neural network

Tags: deep-learning, convolution

Suppose I have a CNN which is trained for classifying images of different animals, the output of such model will be a point (*output point*) in a `n` spatial dimension, where `n` is the number of animal classes the model is trained on; then that output is transformed in a way to convert it into a *one-hot* vector of `n` parameters, giving then the correct label for the image from the point of view of the CNN, but let's stick with the `n` dimensional point, which is the **concept** of an input image.

Suppose then that I want to take that point and transform it in a way so that the final output is an image with constraint width and height (the dimensions should be the same with different input images) which outputs the same point as the input image's, how do I do that?

I'm basically asking for the methods used (training mostly) for this kind of task, where an image must be reconstructed based on the output point of the CNN -I know the image will never be identical, but I'm looking for images that generate the same (or at least not so different) output point as a input image when that point is inputted to the CNN-. Take in mind that the input of the model I'm asking for is `n` and the output is a two (or three if it's not in grayscale) dimensional tensor. I noticed that *deepdream* does exactly this kind of thing (I think), but every time I put "deepdream" and "generate" in Google, an online generator is almost always shown, not the actual techniques; so if there are some answers to this I'd love to hear about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output label does not contain enough information to reconstruct an entire image.

Quoting from the [DeepDream example ipython notebook](https://github.com/google/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb):

> Making the "dream" images is very simple. Essentially it is just a gradient ascent process that tries to maximize the L2 norm of activations of a particular DNN layer.

So the algorithm modifies an existing image such that outputs of certain nodes in the network (can be in an intermediate layer, not necessarily the output nodes) become large. In order to do that, it has to calculate the gradient of the node output with respect to the input pixels.

Comment: So the net must be trained everytime before producing a new image? Isn't there a way to, say, generate an image of an animal knowing beforehand what constitutes an animal?